# Getting size of document libraries in site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I'm trying to get a list of the size of all the document libraries in my site collection.  I don't have access to central admin, and I don't have access to the server so I can't hit the object model.  I am a site collection administrator and I can access the web services.

The data I want is actually here: `_layouts/storman.aspx`, except I can only view 100 libraries.

Other code I've found that does what I want is this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername"))
{
    DataTable tbl;
    tbl = site.StorageManagementInformation(
        SPSite.StorageManagementInformationType.DocumentLibrary,
        SPSite.StorageManagementSortOrder.Decreasing,
        SPSite.StorageManagementSortedOn.Size, 100);
    foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in tbl.Columns)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doc Lib Name :" + row["Title"].ToString() + "  Size (bytes): " + row["Size"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Since I can't run code on the server, can anyone point me to a web service that exposes this same functionality?  I can't find it for the life of me.

Enabling more than 100 rows in the above-referenced report would also work great.

Comment: have you looked under site collection administration in site settings at the site usage reports?

Comment: site usage reports doesn't give me any detail about the document libraries within my subsites.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the explorer view, and the windows property window ?

In fact, you may try (a guess, I never did it) to use webdav protocol. It may contains what you are looking for.

Comment: I found an excellent link that shows how to map a drive to a site collection using WebDav.  Unfortunately, they've turned off webdav on our site, so that's no-go.  Link for posterity: http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/09/29/sharepoint-2010-storman-on-steroids.aspx